# Interpretate garch(1,1)-results

Tags: r

How should I read the results I got from my Garch-model?
Does this mean that none of my external regressors had any impact?

```
Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(1,0,0)
Distribution    : ghyp 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
          Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu        0.007363    0.005930   1.241772 0.214321
ar1       0.088732    0.031644   2.804059 0.005046
omega     0.000002    0.000004   0.534986 0.592660
alpha1    0.049419    0.015292   3.231603 0.001231
beta1     0.863324    0.006810 126.771068 0.000000
vxreg1    0.000000    0.002269   0.000004 0.999996
vxreg2    0.000000    0.000000   1.724852 0.084554
vxreg3    0.000000    0.000000   0.595820 0.551296
vxreg4    0.000000    0.000317   0.000032 0.999975
vxreg5    0.000000    0.000157   0.000064 0.999949
vxreg6    0.000000    0.000000   0.027500 0.978061
vxreg7    0.000000    0.000000   0.000000 1.000000
vxreg8    0.000000    0.000067   0.000149 0.999881
skew      0.206258    0.233379   0.883791 0.376809
shape     1.882771    0.128208  14.685333 0.000000
ghlambda -0.464969    0.508095  -0.915121 0.360128
```

Comment: There is a lot of information missing to answer that question but it looks like your function has failed to converge to the true values.